# Select first unique match for each ID in data.table (r)

Tags: r, join, filter, data.table

I have a data.table that consists of 3 columns. The first 2 are key IDs and the 3rd column represents all possible values that an ID can have.

Here is an example:

```
DT <- data.table( 
            Pol_No = c('a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c')  
          , Veh_No = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,3,3,3)
          , Value = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5)
          )
DT
    Pol_No Veh_No Value
 1:      a      1     1
 2:      b      1     1
 3:      b      2     2
 4:      c      1     3
 5:      c      1     4
 6:      c      1     5
 7:      c      2     6
 8:      c      3     3
 9:      c      3     4
10:      c      3     5
```

I need to filter this table such that Value is unique for each Policy & Vehicle.  So Row 4 would stay, but Row 9 would be filtered because the value of 4 would have already been assigned for [Pol_No:c , Veh_No:1]

The expected result is:

```
   Pol_No Veh_No Value
1:      a      1     1
2:      b      1     1
3:      b      2     2
4:      c      1     3
5:      c      2     6
6:      c      3     4
```

I've tried a lot of possibilities but the best I can come up with is:

```
Flt <- 
  DT[DT
     , .(Value)
     , on = .(Pol_No , Veh_No )
     , mult = 'first']
DT[ Value == Flt$Value,]

   Pol_No Veh_No Value
1:      a      1     1
2:      b      1     1
3:      b      2     2
4:      c      1     3
5:      c      2     6
6:      c      3     3
```

This is almost correct, but the Value for [c,3] has already been used in [c,1] so its still wrong.

Any idea on how to filter out a row if its already been used in the same key set?

Comment: May be a recursive option is possible `out <- DT[0];for(nm in unique(DT$Pol_No)) {tmp <- DT[Pol_No == nm]; for(nm2 in unique(tmp$Veh_No)) {tmp2 <- na.omit(tmp)[Veh_No == nm2];out <- rbind(out, tmp2[1]); tmp[Value %in% tmp2$Value[1], Value := NA]}}; out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
DT[,Count := sequence(.N),by = .(Pol_No,Value)][,.SD[min(Count),],by = .(Pol_No,Veh_No)]
   Pol_No Veh_No Value Count
1:      a      1     1     1
2:      b      1     1     1
3:      b      2     2     1
4:      c      1     3     1
5:      c      2     6     1
6:      c      3     4     2
```

You can get rid of the `Count` column later.

Comment: Amazing!  I noticed it doesn't work when Value isn't sorted, but that's okay.  The only other thing I noticed was that when there isn't an acceptable value because it was used in previous vehicles, it returns a value already used.

e.g.
DT <- data.table(
            Pol_No = c('a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c')
          , Veh_No = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5)
          , Value = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,2,3,2,3)
          )

[c,5] returns 3 when I would like to just filter.  I believe I have a workaround that I'll add.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Really, this is a complicated set optimization problem. I'm following along hoping someone comes up with a better solution. Hopefully this will get you most of the way.

Comment: Cool `data.table` solution with brilliant idea! Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ian Campbell for solving the hardest part! I didn't mention this in my original post, but in cases where all acceptable values were used in previous vehicles, the table should filter the row as well (rather than return an already used Value)

e.g.

```
DT <- data.table(
            Pol_No = c('a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c')
          , Veh_No = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5)
          , Value = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,2,3,2,3)
          )
```

Using Ian's code:

```
DT2 <- DT[,Count := sequence(.N),by = .(Pol_No,Value)][,.SD[min(Count),],by = .(Pol_No,Veh_No)][,Count:=NULL][]
```

And then adding the next filter seems to do the trick

```
DT2 <- DT2[, Dup :=  seq(.N) , by = c('Pol_No', 'Value') ]
DT2[Dup == 1,][,Dup:=NULL]

1:      a      1     1
2:      b      1     1
3:      b      2     2
4:      c      1     3
5:      c      2     6
6:      c      3     4
7:      c      4     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive function that may help

```
f <- function(dt) {
  if (nrow(dt) == 1) {
    return(dt)
  }
  u <- f(dt[-.N])
  v <- dt[.N]
  if (all(is.na(u[v, Value, on = .(Pol_No, Veh_No)]) & !v[, Value] %in% u[Pol_No == v[, Pol_No], Value])) {
    return(rbind(u, v))
  }
  return(u)
}
```

such that

```
> f(DT)
   Pol_No Veh_No Value
1:      a      1     1
2:      b      1     1
3:      b      2     2
4:      c      1     3
5:      c      2     6
6:      c      3     4
```